# Custom Helpers in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have used html helpers in mvc but i am confused that which could be the scenario where i would need to make custom html helpers in mvc , i have browse over the web and found the following :

here if the value of ImageSource,Imagename,ImageDescription will be null than view will throw error so by using custom html helper for the same we could get rid from conditional code and use our own custom helper method . but is that only reason to make custom html helpers what could be other scenario to use custom html helpers?

Comment: For any time you want to generate generate valid html for a property, class or collection. A simple case might be `@HtmlReadonlyTextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty)` to generate a textbox where the `readonly` attribute is set, to a complex case such a `@Html.TableDisplayFor(m => m.MyCollection)` that might render a table for all properties in the collection including headers an footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many uses for html helpers, one use for example could be to create a helper which creates a

```
<a class='myClass' href='mysite/abc'><img src='myImg' /></a>
```

which you'd call as

```
Html.MyImgA("myClass", "abc", "myImg")
```

More in depth search over the internet will give you other ideas.

Comment: <a class='myClass' href='mysite/abc'><img src='myImg' /></a>       in this case we could also use <a class='@Model.myClass' href='@Model.Link'><img src='@Model.Src' /></a>   where class name ,Link and Image source is coming from database but in case if any one of it is null view will throw null exception than we have to write some conditional code to prevent that exception , so my question is is this only reason to avoid conditional code to prevent from null exception to write custom html helpers where we could make check conditions and use it across view without conditions check ?

Comment: You can do the same thing by writing the <a> directly onto the page but calling the custom helper is much less code. 

Another use could be to create a helper which gets the number of online users in the system and displays it in a span. Then you just call Html.OnlineUsers() on your pages.

Or if you have a piece of javascript code that you have to put on 10 of your pages, you create another helper which returns the JS code. Later when you need to change the JS, you just update the code in a single place, instead of updating it in 10 separate pages. It has many uses, depends on your needs.

Comment: Also see 2nd answer in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804833/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-html-helpers-best-practices-uses?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804833/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-html-helpers-best-practices-uses?rq=1)